# How to detect teletype/typewriter mode

Tags: fonts, typewriter

How do I detect whether or not I'm in teletype mode in LaTeX?  I'm looking for something like `\ifmmode` or `\mathpalette` or `\mathchoice`.

Perhaps this is an xy problem, so let me give my original context:
I'd like to define versions of some operators that work well in `texttt`.  For example, I'd like a version of `\vdash` that works well enough in a monospaced font.  Here I can define separate ones for tt mode and normal mode, but I'd like a single command that picks which one to use depending on the mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\aswidthof}[2]{\rlap{#1}\hphantom{#2}}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\aswidthof@w}
\newcommand{\aswidthofc}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\aswidthof@w}{#2}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\aswidthof@w/2\relax}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{mmode}}{\mathclap{#1}}{\clap{#1}}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\aswidthof@w/2\relax}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\bettervdash}{\aswidthofc{\ensuremath{\vdash}}{\text{|-}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent \texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\noindent \texttt{a$\vdash$cdefghi$\vdash$klmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\noindent \texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\noindent \texttt{a\bettervdash cdefghi\bettervdash klmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\noindent \texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\noindent $abc\bettervdash def$ \\
\noindent $abc\vdash def$ \\
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered document]

Thoughts I've had:

1. I can try to parse `\the\font`, looking for `tt`
2. I can condition on whether `\widthof{i}` and `\widthof{m}` are equal

Is there a better way?  If not, is there reason to believe that one of these will work more uniformly than the other?

Comment: there is certainly no guarantee that a monospace font will have tt in its name `Courier` for example, or Consolas as used in this site